# What is the best and standard solution for single sign in between two apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im looking for quick and standard solution for synchronizing the user login between two or more applications. I thing is a common problem so i dont want to reinvent the wheel. :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use devise then as long as:

- The database table for users is shared
- Both sites use the same domain or subdomains of the same, and the cookie is set right
- Any salts, and other settings are the same

Everything should be dandy.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i don`t know if is that what I`am looking for. I`am thinking about this architecture DB => REST-ServerApp(only for dealing with DB and storing the autentification) => OtherApps

Comment: Ah. If the apps are quite separated then having them query a central auth server is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

#### OmniAuth

A great place to start is [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) on OmniAuth and Devise. It contains some great pointers.

The [OAuth Gem](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/) is in some ways easier to get to grip with - if you're sold on the idea of OAuth in general.